# referring to json key using variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I am traversing through some multidimensional JSON to retrieve some properties and I am using a variable to reference the object key, but I am receiving an error:

```
unable to get property of undefined or null reference
```

I am referring to using a variable like this:

```
field = ('#something').attr('name');
value1 = json.something1.something2.field.value;
```

When I explicitly declare this without using the variable, like this:

```
value1 = json.something1.something2.the_field.value 
alert(value1);
```

I get a positive result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to access the variable using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) :

```
value1 = json.something1.something2[the_field].value
```

Comment: Thanks that works now. How come it works when I explicitly declare using the dot method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to you use something like:

```
value1 = json.something1.something2[field].value;
```